# How do I compile and run third party code snippet in Haskell securely?

Tags: security, haskell, eval

```
userDefinedFunction = "\x -> x*x :: Int"
main = do
    f <- complileFunction userDefinedFunction :: Int -> Int
    let results = map f [1,2,3,4]
    print $ show results
```

How to do it securely? `userDefinedFunction` is supposed to be untrusted third-party code. It should be built to fast, optimized code, but should not be able to access system directly.

I suppose it should combine [Safe Haskell](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.4.2/docs/html/users_guide/safe-haskell.html) and [System.Eval.Haskell](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/plugins-1.5.1.3/docs/System-Eval-Haskell.html). Are there any projects or tutorials covering this?

Comment: `mueval` was developed with some of these properties in mind.  Sadly, it probably falls short on performance.  It would be great to have some llvm-nacl binding.

Comment: Without performance requirement, something like Lua can be used. I want user-contributed math-intensive code.

Comment: @Vi., Safe Haskell will help (perhaps a lot), but you still have to watch out for memory use (you'll want to use GHC options to limit total heap and stack, and/or use your OS to limit them), CPU time (your OS may be able to help), and of course bugs in GHC.

Comment: @dfeuer, For desktop scenario I consider the resource exhaustion (CPU hog, memory) a low risk, in contrast with user account compromise for running malicious code. A scenario I currently consider: a game with user-contributed levels which are expected to contain performance-critical code.

Comment: @dfeuer, `and of course bugs in GHC` -> Are there any discovered vulnerabilities allowing to escape Safe Haskell at compile- or runtime?

Comment: @Vi., Safe Haskell isn't a security container. It's a way to track certain kinds of safety. Most exploitable GHC bugs would remain exploitable with Safe Haskell. Furthermore, this extends to all "Trustworthy" modules you may choose to allow. I don't personally know what bugs are exploitable, but I'm fairly confident there must be some good ones around.

Comment: @dfeuer, 1. I expect it to be similar to [Java sandboxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html). 2. Somebody has to be the first to receive the first inrush of bugs, to enable a way for a new secure platform later. Desktop game application with user-contributed levels is a good start, as security requirement is not very strict, but obvious means of preventing harm should be taken. I think Safe Haskell-based approach will definitely be safer than "manual" approach (trying to "antivirus" the source code before compilation).

Comment: maybe a vm or container (via docker or rocket)? Docker creates a bridge and can also limit resource consumption.

Comment: @ja, I also want simplicity and portability (including to Windows). That's why OS-dependent solutions are not OK.

Comment: docker runs on Windows, as do many vm hosts.

Comment: @ja., Is it appropriate to embed the Docker into a game to run user-contributed level scripts securely?

Answer (score 1):

There is a wiki page for exactly [this use case](https://wiki.haskell.org/Safely_running_untrusted_Haskell_code)
You could also have a look at lambdabots source code.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.